# jQuery Responsive Navigation in WordPress Child Theme

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm developing a child theme for a WordPress site. The site's responsive navigation was not functional below the 480px breakpoint. The navigation above this breakpoint is being handled by the Superfish jQuery plugin, but that was delivering broken results in phone view. I've removed the classes for the Superfish plugin below 480px, and rolled my own menu.

The menu contains up to three levels of sub-menu items. Everything is hidden at phone view with a hamburger icon with an ID of "trigger" opening the menu. Every menu item that contains a sub-menu item as a descendent has an indicator (with a class of "switch") appended to the end. The click event to toggle open the sub-menus is attached to the "switch" class.

The javascript is as follows:

```
//Removed Superfish classes so new mobile styles can be implemented
if($(window).width() < 480) {
    $('#menu-main-navigation').removeClass('sf-menu sf-js-enabled main-nav');
    $('.sf-with-ul').removeClass('sf-with-ul');
    $('.sf-sub-indicator').remove();
};

//Toggles top-level menu items on click
$('#trigger p, #trigger img').click(function(){
    $('#menu-main-navigation').slideToggle('fast');
});

//If a top-level menu items contains a ul as a descendent, attach an indicator
$('#menu-main-navigation li').has('ul').append('<span class="switch"></span>');

//Add click event to indicator that opens the descendent ul
$('.switch').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle('fast'); 
});
```

This issue that I'm encountering is with the appending of the "switch" element. The element is correctly appended to each top level menu item that contains sub-menu items. However, when the top level  item is opened, the first item in the resulting sub-menu items *always* has the "switch" element appended to it, regardless of whether or not it has sub-menu items. I've removed all classes from the initial jQuery plugin in order prevent conflicts, so the issue has to be in my code, but I can't spot it. Assistance is appreciated.

EDIT: Per Sarah's suggestion, here's a sample of markup.

```
<ul id="menu-main-navigation">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item/a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
      </ul>
      <span class="switch"></span>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Another Item</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SubItem</a></li>
      </ul>
      <span class="switch"></span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Of course, there's all of WordPress's extra classes thrown in there for each list item...but this is the gist of what's going on.

Comment: It's hard to work out without a working example (could you create an example jsfiddle perhaps?) but would changing `#menu-main-navigation li` to `#menu-main-navigation > li` help? so that only the immediate li child has a `.switch` appended to it?

Comment: Please also show some example HTML.

Comment: @Sarah I've edited the question with a sample of the markup. I tried the child selector as you indicated, but no change.

Comment: I've tried to recreate the problem here http://jsfiddle.net/1nsybvdn/ but I'm not seeing the problem you describe. Could you try and recreate it? I didn't copy all of your JS in because you haven't included an example of `#trigger`, but from the looks of your code I doubt that has anything to do with your problem.

Comment: No, #trigger isn't the issue. As you've proven, the code works separate from this particular use case. My conclusion is that there must be some other conflict in the original jQuery plugin that's causing the irregularities. My next course of action is to remove the jQuery plugin from the child theme altogether and build my own solution theme-wide instead of attempting to modify this one for a particular breakpoint. I'll post back with my success on this.